# error on statement execution when creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone please help in explaining the error I get when executing following statement:

Error starting at line 1 in command:
`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "PRODILMOWNER"."ZV_LPEUR_I" ("MANDT","BALANCETYPE", "BRANCH", "CURRENCY", "AMOUNT", "COUNTERPARTY", "COUNTERPARTY_PARENT", "AMOUNT_EUR","DESCRIPTION")
AS
  SELECT a.balancetype,
    a.branch,
    a.currency,
    cast a.amount as number (25,2),
    a.counterparty,
    a.counterparty_parent,
    a.mandt,
    a.description,
   (a.amount*
    (SELECT c.midspot
    FROM ZV_EXCHANGERATES c
    WHERE c.currency =a.currency
    AND c.valuedate  =TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD')
    AND a.valuedate = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MMM-YY')
    ) ) AS cast amount_eur as number (25,2),
  FROM ZT_LP a
```

Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: No more data to read from socket

Comment: Looks like the session got disconnected. Possibly something crashed for some reason.

Comment: "No more data to read from socket" is a generic network communication error, not a syntax error. There may be more details in the instance alert log. However, sometimes a really unlucky syntax error can crash the session, so the first thing to try is removing the `force` and working through the syntax errors such as the missing brackets in the first `cast` expression, and whatever `as cast amount_eur as number (25,2)` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to create view as following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "PRODILMOWNER"."ZV_LPEUR_I" ("MANDT","BALANCETYPE", "BRANCH", "CURRENCY", "AMOUNT", "COUNTERPARTY", "COUNTERPARTY_PARENT", "AMOUNT_EUR","DESCRIPTION")
AS
  SELECT a.balancetype,
    a.branch,
    a.currency,
    cast(a.amount as number(25, 2)) as amount, --cast a.amount as number (25,2),
    a.counterparty,
    a.counterparty_parent,
    a.mandt,
    a.description,
    a.amount*
    (SELECT cast(c.midspot as number(25, 2))
       FROM ZV_EXCHANGERATES c
      WHERE c.currency =a.currency
        AND c.valuedate  =TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD')
        AND a.valuedate = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MMM-YY')
       ) AS amount_eur -- cast amount_eur as number (25,2)  --,
  FROM ZT_LP a;
```

by removing parts right next to dashes(`--`), then no problem remains.

- take casts in paranthesis
- take second cast inside subselect
- remove the comma `,` just before `FROM` clause

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. The requirement is to multiply the amount in a by the midspot in c and force the type of the result to be number (25,2). How would you do that in this case? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ehammer ok, i undertsand now. I've removed the last matter.

Answer (score 2):

You may have other errors, but the correct way to express a `cast` is:

```
cast(a.amount as number(25, 2)) as amount,
```

Note the parentheses and the column alias.